# New to Java script , How to convert for example (1;2;3) in to an java script array

Tags: javascript

I am an SAP developer and need to code in java script for one requirement.

I would like to convert for example (1;2;3) to java script array .

How can i do it . Basically it can be like (10;12;14)   with open and close brackets   not just 1,2,3 or 10,12,14 but it will have brackets  opening and closing . I can have any number of variables in my case . I just gave a sample example . I can also have (1;12;13;12;34;45;46) as well.

I need to convert this in to java script array.
Kindly advice .

Comment: `input.slice(1,-1).split(";").map(Number)` should do the job, but you'd better do this on the server side already and send proper JSON

Comment: tushar , i have opening and closing bracket .

Comment: bergi ,  what is input and map(number) here ? could you please eloborate .I am very new to java script.

Comment: that slice function will remove your opening & closing bracket.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/g`

```js
var re = /\d+/g;
console.log(
  "(1;2;3)".match(re)
  , "1,2,3".match(re)
  , "[10,12,14]".match(re)
  , "(10;12;14)".match(re)
  , "(1;12;13;12;34;45;46)".match(re)
  
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var strOriginal = '(1;2;3)'
var arr = strOriginal.substring(1, strOriginal.length - 1).split(';');
console.log(arr); //["1", "2", "3"]
```

Comment: tarun, i will have only (1;2;3) in some text box . there is no ' symbol in first and last place .

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var array = "(1;12;13;12;34;45;46)".slice(1,-1).split(";");
```

Comment: Hi Zach , Here "(1;12;13;12;12;34;....)"  is a variable it can be any number which is in a text box .  so can i use a variable like X.SLICE(1,-1).SPLIT(";") ;

Comment: Yes any string variable can replace "(1;12...;46)"

Comment: zach, here i have (1;12;13;14) in some text box . so you say that can pass that saying   Var xyx  =  textbox value ; and use xyz.SLICE(1,-1).SPLIT(";") ;

Comment: Yes you can do "(1;12;13;14)".slice(1,-1).split(";");

Comment: what if i dont have " in fornt and back for  that variable.